# How do I display a modal in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For some reason outside my grasp I can't get Vue Modal to work in my Vue-cli installation. Trying to run the modal example from: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

I am still pretty new to Vue, so please excuse my simple question.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
        <transition name="modal">
          <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
              <div class="modal-container">
      
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <slot name="header">
                    default header
                  </slot>
                </div>
      
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <slot name="body">
                    default body
                  </slot>
                </div>
      
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <slot name="footer">
                    default footer
                    <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                      OK
                    </button>
                  </slot>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
      </script>
    <main id="app"></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template'
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  data: {
    showModal: false
  }
})
```

Page.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <!--
      you can use custom content here to overwrite
      default content
    -->
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VueModal',
    methods: {
      hideModal () {
        return this.$store.commit('hideModal')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is Page.vue what is being imported as App.vue?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using Vuex, so your use of `this.$store.commit` is puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not using `Vuex`, therefore the line of code

```
return this.$store.commit('hideModal')
```

won't work.

Also, your `showModal` is in `Main.js` instead of your `Page.vue`, and you actually are not using the method `hideModal()`, modify your script in `Page.vue` like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VueModal',
    data() {
      return { showModal: false };
    }
  }
</script>
```