# Vue-cli cannot show modal window

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have created a vue-cli application and what I have right now:

1. **Main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Element)
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

2. **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <head>
    <title>SmartPlanPlus</title>
  </head>
  <SmartPlan/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SmartPlan from './components/SmartPlan.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    SmartPlan
  }
}
</script>
```

3. **SmartPlan.vue**

```
<template>
 <div id="app">  
  <el-container>
  <el-header>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <el-button icon="el-icon-folder-opened" circle @click="showModal = true">
        </el-button>
        <modal :show="showModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </el-header>
  <el-main>
  <svg overflow="scroll" viewBox="0 0 500 250"><g id="svg_obj" transform="translate(0,200) scale(1,-1)"></g></svg>
  </el-main>
  <el-footer>
  </el-footer>
  </el-container>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

import modal from '../components/PlanList.vue'

export default {
  name: 'SmartPlan',
  props: {
  },
  components: {
    modal
  }
}
</script>
```

4. **PlanList.vue**

```
<template>
    <transition name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask" v-show="show">
            <div class="modal-container">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>New Post</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label class="form-label">
                        Title
                        <input class="form-control">
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-label">
                        Body
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer text-right">
                    <button class="modal-default-button" @click="savePost()">
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'modal',
    props: ['show'],
}
</script>
```

I have checked almost all examples like:

- https://adamwathan.me/2016/01/04/composing-reusable-modal-dialogs-with-vuejs/
- [Cant get Vue Modal to work in Vue-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683449/cant-get-vue-modal-to-work-in-vue-cli)

I want a modal window to popup on a button press on SmartPlan, but it does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where is your showModal data value ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 I have tried to add it to main.js like:   data: {
    showModal: false
  } but I'm getting an error: Property or method "showModal" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: then how you could pass it to modal if its not available in your component ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 I have no idea. As I mentioned earlier - I'm new in vue. What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **SmartPlan.vue** forgot to put a showModal data in your data model. Put this like this one

```
export default {
  name: 'SmartPlan',
  data() {
     return {
        showModal:false
     }
  }
  props: {
  },
  components: {
    modal
  }
}
```